# Angular $http request in the controller does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller. It works all fine (it parses the data and sends them into the view). The only problem I have is that it does not send $http request. Here is the code block of controller (i just send a test $http without any value from the view just to test it works or not, which does not work):
(It's also worth mentioning that I check via browser's console to see if any ajax request is sent or not)

```
// Controller
LoginApp.controller("RegisterController", function($scope, $http, registerService){

        var username  = null;
        var password = null;

        $scope.registerSubmit  = function(){
            username = $scope.register.username;
            password = $scope.register.password;


        };


        //registerService.CheckUser();
        $http.post('server.php', {name : 'something'})

            .success(function(data, status, header, config){

                return data;

            })

            .error(function(data, status, header, config){

                return data;

            }); // end of $http request
    });
```

**EDIT:** I have edited what @JoshBeam has recommended, passing data to the post(), but it does not change anything.

Comment: According to the [angularJS api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post), $http.post requires some data. Try sending an empty object for testing, eg. `$http.post("server.php", {})` or something like that.

Comment: What you're doing should work fine (see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahchurch/Psq7P/1/) - are you seeing any other errors? Can we see the view code that you have set up? Wondering if your controller just isn't getting called, check your routes too...

Comment: Is your controller defined in your html? Make sure your controller is being used. Also it looks like your code is not doing anything, the `return data` is not being used anywhere in your code.

Comment: I wonder if you're just not seeing the request in your console for some reason. Replace `return data` with `console.log(data)` in both callbacks.

Comment: Any errors being printed to the console? The only thing I can think of is that an error is being thrown before you controller is instantiated which causes the $http to never be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass data along with the HTTP request. According to the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#post), it is in this format: `post(url, data, [config]);`

Thus:

```
$http.post('server.php', /* your data */);
```

Comment: @MT-Developer, What doesn't work? Does the HTTP request send data to the server? Also, if you use `return data`, it will not update anything, since XMLHttpRequests are asynchronous.